Exact approximation in $p$ adic
Given a non increasing function $\psi$ the $\psi$ approximable points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as
$W(\psi)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|qx-p|<\psi(q)\}$ for infinitely many $(q,p)\in \mathbb{Z}^m\times\mathbb{Z}$. Now then one defines exact $\psi$ approximable vector as $E(\psi)=W(\psi)\setminus\cup_{c<1} W(c\psi)$.
I had read many results concerning $E(\psi)$ in classical setting. But I am unable to find any result concerning $E(\psi)$ say the Hausdorff dimension of the set in the setting of field of formal series or even $p$ adic field. I am just curious to know whether the exact approximable notion in these fields as norm is discrete somehow gives some trivial things.
There are results concerning size of Badly approximable vectors in these settings but I couldn't find anything related to exact approximable vectors in these setting. Any reference if there are any will be extremely beneficial. Or if that is not interesting in $Q_p$ any comment regarding that also is also very helpful.

Please don't self-vandalize your own question. You can delete it: it will not be erased and you can undelete it subsequently after possible modifications.

I tried to delete it couldn't as I found the answer I was searching for.

If possible please delete it from your end.
